# Token expired or deleted show login pop up in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular2-jwt

I am application used token based authentication using JwtHelper, by canActivate method validating the router change and redirecting to the login page.

But the page is not redirecting to login page after token expired or deleting the local storage.

How can I validate in all the action of the application?

Answer (score 0):

The guard works only at routing level, for your need, I would suggest you to set up an Observable for token changes so that in your page you can subscribe into it and now exactly when the token has expired or deleted.